# Laravel notification not working when using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have a system formed with a main backend and some microservices. In the backend, I have an endpoint which executes the code below and triggers a Laravel Notification. If I hit that endpoint with Postman, for example, it goes without problem.

```
    try {
        Notification::send($this->getUsersByProjectId($request->project_id), new IncomingMessage(
        array_merge(
            $request->all(),
                [
                    'from' => json_decode($this->getGuest($request->from)->getContent())[0]
                ])));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }

    return response()->json(
        'Received',
        200
    );
```

The problem is when I hit that endpoint from one of the microservices using Guzzle. The Notification is not triggered but there's no error message at all (neither in logs files). Below is the code from the microservice which calls the backend endpoint.

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => getenv('BACKEND_API'),
    ]);

}

public function sendFromTablet(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'project_id' => 'required|uuid',
        'to' => 'required|uuid', // contact uuid / backend
        'from' => 'required|uuid', // guest uuid / tablet
        'language_to' => 'required|string',
        'language_from' => 'required|string',
        'is_reply' => 'filled|uuid',
        'is_notification' => 'filled|boolean',
        'message' => 'required|string',
        'media_file' => 'filled|array',
        'location' => 'filled|array',
        'place' => 'filled|uuid',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['source'] = 'tablet';
    $data['message'] = $this->createMessageObject($data);
    $message = Message::make($data);
    dd($this->sendToBackend($message));

    $message->save();

    return response()->json($message, 201);
}

public function sendToBackend($message) {

    return $this->client->request('POST', '/api/new-message', [
        'form_params' => $message->toArray()
    ])->getBody()->getContents();

}
```

Output of Guzzle Debug

- Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x6bacea3ed0)
- Trying 127.0.0.1...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x6bacea3ed0)
- Connected to backend.local (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)

> POST /api/new-message HTTP/1.1
> Host: backend.local
> User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.1 curl/7.64.0 PHP/7.2.19
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 241

- upload completely sent off: 241 out of 241 bytes
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 06:45:23 GMT < Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.2.19 <
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.19 < Cache-Control: no-cache, private < X-RateLimit-Limit: 60 < X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57 <
  Content-Length: 10 < Content-Type: application/json < * Connection #0 to host backend.local left intact "

Thank you for your help.

PS: I'm using Laravel Websockets by Beyond Code for getting real-time notifications.

Edit: To make this work, I've had to change the order of the request, so the main request is to the backend and the backend is the one who calls the microservice. The other way I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: I can't guess what is wrong but maybe we can debug a bit ... can you check the access logs? Is Guzzle hitting the endpoint? And if it is, what response is received by the microservice?

Comment: @lornamitchell What do you mean with access logs? The ones stored at /storage/logs? If so, there's nothing there. And yes, Guzzle hits the endpoint and there's no error at all. After the code I posted I have a 'return response' which executes normally. PS: I have just edited the code to show the complete function.

Comment: Yes, storage/logs would be the default location. Try adding more log output to the route before and after the notification is sent? This will help you to understand if the code path you expect is being followed.

Comment: try using`catch (RequestException $e) {
    $error['request'] = Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        $error['response'] =  Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
    } Log::info($error);
}` also you add `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;`

Comment: I've debugged through all the methods and classes that Notification follows, but the execution is just fine, there's nothing strange. I've also tried what @bhucho says, but as there is no error or exception, it isn't executed.

Comment: try using debug in guzzle , it shows step by step occurence in the request, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug

Comment: I have just added the output of guzzle debug @bhucho , although I don't see anything special